# load with await before express starts

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have a settings.js file

`module.exports  = {'a': 1}`

from another file
`const set = require('settings')`

but now I want to load data from an API (AWS secret manager )

how do I do sync using `await`? I can't use `await` from main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Promise:

`setting.js`

```
module.exports = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    loadAPI(function(response) {
        data = response

        resolve(data);
    });
});
```

`another.js`

```
var set = require('./setting.js').then(function(data){
    //Here code using foo;
});
```

Comment: i'm using `require('./setting.js')` alot in my code and that will invoke a major change. any other suggestion?